# python social auth getting authenticated user details

Tags: python, django

I have an application that uses Python Social Auth to connect to various SM sites, both for login and to retrieve data from the other sites. If the user is logged in how can I retrive their User ID (that relates to the Django user)? I am trying to access this outside a view, and I thought was able to access some of the available methods in strategy such as get_user which is listed here but can't find this documented or how to use it?

```
(Pdb) pp dir(strategy)
['ALLOWED_CHARS',
 'DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_STRATEGY',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'absolute_uri',
 'authenticate',
 'build_absolute_uri',
 'clean_partial_pipeline',
 'create_user',
 'from_session_value',
 'get_backends',
 'get_disconnect_pipeline',
 'get_language',
 'get_pipeline',
 'get_setting',
 'get_user',
 'html',
 'openid_session_dict',
 'openid_store',
 'partial_from_session',
 'partial_to_session',
 'random_string',
 'redirect',
 'render_html',
 'request',
 'request_data',
 'request_get',
 'request_host',
 'request_is_secure',
 'request_path',
 'request_port',
 'request_post',
 'send_email_validation',
 'session',
 'session_get',
 'session_pop',
 'session_set',
 'session_setdefault',
 'setting',
 'storage',
 'to_session_value',
 'tpl',
 'validate_email']
```